# Code compiles until CreateWnd() is thrown in

Tags: c++, delphi, linker-errors, c++builder, delphi-xe3

I am using XE3 and trying to construct a DLL with my third party component.  Since it is a rather large project I will describe it then detail the question at hand.

I have multiple cpp files and multiple header files(classes in header files, functions in cpp files).  I have everything linking and compiling fine UNTIL I put a `CreateWnd()` function into one of my classes

```
void __fastcall TICSByteEntry::CreateWnd(void)
{
    TCustomControl::CreateWnd();
    SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE) | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
}
```

Now it will compile with this code in it but when I put my component on a form and try to run THAT project it will give me an error 
'*[ilink32 error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall TICSByteEntry::CreateWnd() referenced from 'path'unit1.obj*'

No other linking issues just that one and as soon as I comment it out everything works nicely as expected.  When I was researching this online someone said it is having problems finding the entry point **http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27343**.  I tried what was recommended and no luck. Any one want to take a guess on what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried linking to the definition?

Comment: Does the `unit1` project include the cpp file that defines this..or is this in a static library, are you referencing the static library. I typically use VS for development, but it sounds like you are missing a linker reference or linker include statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding `CreateWnd()` you should override `CreateParams()`. That way the window is created with the style you want and does not need to be changed after creation.